# NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/mobile/client/AWSMobileClient

Tags: android, aws-amplify

I have an issue with AWS Amplify for Android. I am using Cognito and S3, both configured though Amplify. When I init my app it crashes for API level lower than 21. If I run it with API level 21 or higher, it runs successfully. This is the exception:

```
07-28 22:02:08.693 5105-5105/com.marcast.sistmovildonatto.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/mobile/client/AWSMobileClient
        at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.<init>(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.java:103)
        at com.marcast.sistmovildonatto.DidonatoApplication.onCreate(DidonatoApplication.kt:16)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.<init>(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.java:103) 
        at com.marcast.sistmovildonatto.DidonatoApplication.onCreate(DidonatoApplication.kt:16) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using guest authentication with Cognito, and S3 with public access to objects. The crash occurs here:

```kotlin
class DidonatoApplication: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        try {
            Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin()) //HERE throws exception
            Amplify.addPlugin(AWSS3StoragePlugin())
            Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
            Log.i("DidonatoMobile", "Initialized Amplify")
        } catch (error: AmplifyException) {
            Log.e("DidonatoMobile", "Could not initialize Amplify", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Any one have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi Matias thanks for raising https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/657 in the Amplify Android repo. Leaving a link here for cross-reference. - Amplify team.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but a different class definition that couldn't be found.

I noticed that my implementations for the various Amplify plugins in the build.gradle file used different versions. Matching the versions fixed the errors (in my case I went with my lowest version - 1.0.0).